# MongoDB doctrine ODM OneToMany not resolving to DB ref

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm

YAML mapping doc
**User**

```
User
    slug:
      unique:
        order: desc
      type: string
    roles:
            reference: true
            type: many
            targetDocument: Role
            cascade: all
```

**Role**

```
Role:
  type: document
  collection: Role
  fields:
    name:
        id: true
        strategy: none
        type: string
```

Now adding new role to that user updating a blank object without storing any DB  ref and no error. `$user->getRoles()` returns array of Role object. As reference are by default stored as DbRef, i was expecting the entry would be a DbRef. But it is not in this case.

```
 $updateApprove = $this->persistantManager->createQueryBuilder('User')
                ->field('slug')
                ->equals($user->getSlug())
                ->findAndUpdate()
                ->returnNew()
                ->field('roles');


            $updateApprove->set($user->getRoles());
            $updatedUser = $updateApprove->getQuery()
                ->execute();
```

Data in db after for roles executing field is showing as

```
 "roles" : [ 
        {}, 
        {}
    ]
```

Comment: The problem is that query builder will do only little to no transformations of objects you feed it. If you need it to insert DBRefs, you must give it DBRefs.

Comment: @malarzm you mean if i need to insert db ref. first i need to pull the data (roles) from the db (as it will be managed document) and then use those to insert it. right?

Comment: More that you need to have a document(s), get a DBRef for them with [`DocumentManager::createDBRef`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/f7379e4eeaffcd33d83fb4b0fcc4ccce1acb8a4e/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentManager.php#L679) and then pass that to query builder.